# Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass, Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, speech, avspeechsynthesizer

Working thru this appcoder tutorial [building a text to speech app tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/text-to-speech-ios-tutorial/) and run into a swift 1.2-> swift 2.0 feature.

The demo project has a class in it... which the Xcode 7.1.1 under IOS 10.11.1 doesn't like, giving me the error. "initialiser doesn't override the designated initialiser from its super class" on the override init() statement, followed by the error "Must call the designated initialiser of the superclass UISlider".

Ok, Rather new to Swift; and quite where I start to fix this is a little lost on me.

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

var sliderIdentifier: Int!

override init() { <--- error here
    super.init()  <--- error here

    sliderIdentifier = 0
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    sliderIdentifier = 0
}

}
```

What should this code snippet say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `UISlider` doesn't define or inherit `init()` as a designated initializer, you can't call it from your subclass `init`.

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    var sliderIdentifier: Int!

    required init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        sliderIdentifier = 0
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sliderIdentifier = 0
    }

}
```

In this case, you could factor out the initialization of `sliderIdentifier` and just inherit all of `UISlider`s initializers:

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

    var sliderIdentifier: Int! = 0

}
```

For more information, read the section titled “Designated Initializers and Convenience Initializers” in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203).